# Why is there no "is" in "Valhalla calling me"?

Tags: sentence-construction

Why are linking verbs or helping verbs sometimes omitted? Is it for a rhyme/rhythm in the sentence? Below is the lyrics of the song "Valhalla calling me". Why did the writer omit "is" in "Valhalla calling me"?

The 2nd line has no verb in it. How is that possible? What does this type of sentence structure usually mean? (I have found a similar sentence structure, where there is no finite verb, in many songs)

Lyrics:

> Ships on vigor of the waves are skimming
> Barren summits to the verdant plains
> Each horizon is a new beginning
> Rise and reign
> Far from the fjords and the ice cold currents
> Ravens soar over new frontiers
> Songs and sagas of a fate determined
> Shields and spears
> Vows of favour or the thrill of plunder
> Pull together for the clan and kin
> Clank of hammers and the crash of thunder
> Pound within
> Oh-ho-oh
> The echoes of eternity
> Oh-ho-oh
> **Valhalla calling me**
> Oh-ho-oh
> To pluck the strings of destiny
> Oh-ho-oh
> **Valhalla calling me**
> **Valhalla calling me**

Comment: In this case, the name of the song is *Vahalla Calling*. So he did it here to paint a picture -- all of his images are examples of Vahalla calling him. If it helps, song lyrics are more like poetry than narrative.

Comment: Because it's a song.  Here's a poem I wrote.  **Birds!  Buildings!  Windows!**  Are you wondering why there are no verbs?

Comment: These three are just nouns perhaps?

Comment: @RADS - Correct.  In a poem, as well as a song, I can do anything I want to do with the English language.  Often times I may do something that has never been done before. **A bird me swallered as me stomach turned soured.** Might be a good poem but I wouldn't spend too much time trying to understand the structure.  Poems and songs are not good places to begin an understanding of the mechanical structure of the language.

Comment: I am sure that whatever RADS language is, the same phenomenon occurs or a similar one.

Comment: Yes......U r right

Comment: ...I am just confused that if these sentences r written...same example 'Valhalla calling me'.......How should I comprehend in my mind.... should it be understood like 'he is being called by Valhalla'............or should I understand' calling' as Adjectival Participle or sth else. But guessing from replies I think it should be understood as the first one.....?...........and yes.....I have understood that we shouldn't search for grammatical explanations in Songs and poems

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Astralbee says, poems and song lyrics often don't follow grammar rules very strictly. The writer will break grammar rules -- rearrange word order, leave out words that aren't essential to convey the meaning, etc -- to get a desired rhyme or rhythm.

In this case, yes, the intended meaning is "Valhalla is calling me" or "These things are Valhalla calling me".

RE the second line doesn't have a verb: The first and second lines together are one sentence. "Ships on vigor of the waves are skimming barren summits to the verdant plains." That is, the ships are skimming barren summits. In a poem or song lyrics, a line may be one sentence, or there could be several lines making up one sentence, or several sentences on one line, or sometimes even a sentence will end in the middle of a line and a new one begins.

Comment: I don't understand the sentence 'These things r Valhalla calling me'.........

Comment: I meant, the ships skimming the sumits, the ravens soaring, etc, all are Valhalla calling to me. Valhalla is calling me through these things.

Answer (score 4):

First thing to understand is that this is a song - lyrics and poetry don't need to strictly follow the rules of grammar. They must of course be understandable, but things like rhyme schemes and syllable count are often more important than grammatical structure.

That said, "Valhalla Calling" does not necessarily require an auxiliary verb (ie "Valhalla *is* calling".

Consider:

> - Outside the window, men *are* working.
> - Outside, I see men working.
>
> ---
>
> - Birds are singing
> - I hear birds singing.

In my two examples, the options with auxiliary verbs are what you might say if you were making a statement without any prior context. The options without auxiliary verbs are what you might say if you had already established that you were describing what you can see or hear, or what you might reply if you had been asked. Song lyrics and poetry are often written from a 'third person' point of view. You might find [this article](https://courses.lumenlearning.com/atd-distanceminnesota-creativewriting/chapter/lesson-10-voice-in-poetry/) on voices in poetry helpful.